# Job processing with a traditional worker or using a Node server?

Tags: node.js, ruby, worker

I want to be able to process background jobs that will have multiple tasks associated with it. Tasks may consist of launching API requests (blocking operations) and manipulating and persisting responses. Some of these tasks could also have subtasks that must be executed asynchronously.

For languages such as Ruby, I might use a worker to execute the jobs. As I understand, every time a new job comes gets to the queue, a new thread will execute it. As I mentioned before, sometimes a task could contain a series of subtasks to be executed asynchronously, so as I see it, I have two options:

- Add the substep execution to the worker queue (But a job could have easily lots of subtasks that will fill the queue fast and will block new jobs from been processed).
- What if I use event-driven Node server to handle a job execution? I would not need to add subtasks to a queue as a single node server could be able to handle one's job entire execution asynchronously. Is there something wrong with doing this?

This is the first time I encounter this kind of problem and I want to know which approach is better suited to solve my issue.

Comment: With Sidekiq for example, each worker can have multiple threads, that it fills with jobs from the queue. You can also  configure workers to read from certain queues only, and categorize the jobs as such, to prevent all workers from getting filled up with a certain long-running job type. I'm not saying this is necessarily better than using a Node server, which may have more lightweight threads. But for scalability, in either case you probably will want to support horizontal scaling (multiple workers).

Comment: There's too many other unknowns (your exp. w/ both languages, the infra/stack you're using, etc.) I'd say worrying about the queue filling up is a premature optimization, and would say build it the best you can build it, but be prepared to rewrite it when you outgrow it. You might as well be comparing Kafka & RabbitMQ alongside (just use Sidekiq if you're experienced with ruby, or a node-based tool if you're more comfortable with node). Sidekiq will be pretty easy to setup if you're deploying to Heroku